# Multi-Touch Soft Keyboard Functionality In Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I am developing a keyboard in Android (a braille keyboard, specifically). For those of you who do not know, braille is composed of six dots, and combinations of these dots form symbols. I wrote a keyboard using the KeyboardView class with the basic listener, but the problem is this: the default listener only allows for one key to be pressed at a time. To form the letter l requires three dots (dots 1, 2 and 3). I have to press each key individually, followed by the spacebar to write the letter. I would like the keyboard to function in a different way; all dots can be pressed simultaneously, and when the dots are released, the letter is written.
Am I right when thinking this is impossible with the listener bundled with KeyboardView? If I rewrite the onTouch routine in the KeyboardView, would this latter functionality be possible? Does the OnTouch function detect multiple action_down events simultaneously? I was thinking that if this is possible, I can determine the x-y coordinates of the press, loop through the keys on the keyboard, and determine which keys are being pressed. If this is not possible, will I have to go a step below this and write onTouch for a basic view?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make some quick tests to a keyboard, like a new key layout or a new predictive text algorithm, KeyboardView is fine.  If you're doing anything more complicated KeyboardView just doesn't have any real flexibility.  None of the major keyboards use it (and I know that for sure, I wrote one of them and have talked to engineers at the others).

You could rewrite onTouch or put in a touch listener on the existing keyboard view, but then you're going to have to do a lot of work inside of their framework, such as hit testing to determine what key is touched.  At that point its probably easier to just write your own from scratch.  I almost guarantee you will at some point anyway if you go all the way to a commercial product.

You can use onTouch to get multiple fingers down, but it won't be on ACTION_DOWN.  You get an ACTION_DOWN for the first finger down, then an ACTION_POINTER_DOWN for each additional finger.  This is how it works for any view.  Then any motion on any finger will generate an ACTION_MOVE.  When fingers are released you get an ACTION_POINTER_UP for all fingers until the last, which gets an ACTION_UP.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'm going to use the KeyboardView to place the keys, but I will rewrite the onTouch routine. The Key class just seems nice because there are methods that will return true if the x-y values passed into them hit one of the keys. I can define the positions from an XML file.